# Excel slicer - formatting individual buttons to have unique colors

Tags: excel, slicers

My organization is using Excel 2010. My question is whether it is possible to format slicer buttons with custom colors, so that Button1 = Red, Button2 = Green, Button3 = Yellow, etc?

I understand that Slicer Styles menu give the user the choice of pre-set styles or the creation of a new style, but the user is unable to choose a unique color for individual buttons.

Could this be done with VBA or some other means?

Answer (score 0):

Nope, VBA won't let you do that either.